# pdftk Error: Failed to open PDF file:

Tags: php, pdf, pdftk

I am using `pdftk` library to extract the form fields from the pdf .Everything is just running fine except the one issue that i got a pdf file [pdf file link](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-9.pdf). which causes the error is given bellow

```
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-9.pdf
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

command for this is

```
root@ri8-MS-7788:/home/ri-8# pdftk http://192.168.1.43/form/i-9.pdf dump_data_fields
```

the same command is working for all other forms .

**Attempt1**

I have tried to encrypt the pdf to unsafe version but it produce the same error . here is the command

```
pdftk http://192.168.1.43/forms/i-9.pdf input_pw foopass output /var/www/forms/un-i-9.pdf
```

**Update**

this is my full function to handle this

```
public function Formanalysis($pdfname) 
    {
         $pdffile=Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/uploads/forms/'.$pdfname;
        exec("pdftk ".$pdffile." dump_data_fields 2>&1", $output,$retval);
        //got an error for some pdf if these are secure 
        if(strpos($output[0],'Error') !== false)
        {
            $unsafepdf=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/uploads/forms/un-'.$pdfname;
            //echo "pdftk ".$pdffile." input_pw foopass output ".$unsafepdf;
            exec("pdftk ".$pdffile." input_pw foopass output ".$unsafepdf);
            exec("pdftk ".$unsafepdf." dump_data_fields 2>&1", $outputunsafe,$retval);
            return $outputunsafe ;
            //$response=array('0'=>'error','error'=>$output[0]);
            //return $response;

        }

        //if (strpos($output[0],'Error') !== false){ echo  "error to run" ; }   // this is the option to handle error 
        return $output;

    }
```

Comment: you can use pdftk, only pay attention to these details: 1 = download and use latest build or compile from pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-version-history; 2 = this pdf has restrictions (owner password) applied; you need to remove restrictions before to use pdftk. you can do this with qpdf qpdf.sourceforge.net qpdf --decrypt *.pdf output.pdf, then you can use pdftk without pains

Comment: in fact, only very old builds (pdftk 1.41) have no support for pdf version>1.4/1.5, newer fully support these versions and beyond

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this may be a little trick solution but should work for you . as @bruno said that this is encrypted file . You should decrypt this before you use for the `pdftk` . For this i found a way to decrypt that is `qpdf` a free opem source library to decrypt the pdf, remove the owner and user passwords etc and many more. You can find this here [Qpdf](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fqpdf.sourceforge.net%2Ffiles%2Fqpdf-manual.html&ei=IU5YVcWpEY-6uATtg4G4Cw&usg=AFQjCNFISmWtBgSpPob0DyQcg6IC3br0Uw&bvm=bv.93564037,d.c2E). install it on your system . and run this command

```
qpdf --decrypt input.pdf output.pdf
```

then use the output file in the `pdftk` command . it should work .

Comment: Where did Bruno say the document was encrypted?

Comment: This decrypting seems to have done trick when performed a a problem child Word pdf I'm trying to merge with some other pdfs.

Answer (score 14):

PdfTk is a tool that was created by compiling [an obsolete version of iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially) to an executable using the GNU Compiler for Java (GCJ) (PdfTk is not endorsed by iText Group NV).

I have examined your PDF and it uses two technologies that weren't supported by iText at the time PdfTk was created: XFA and compressed cross-reference tables.

The latter is what causes your problem. PdfTk expects your file to end like this:

```
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000258 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000346 00000 n 
0000000146 00000 n 
0000000397 00000 n 
0000000442 00000 n 
trailer
<</ID [<c8bf0ac531b0fc7b5b9ec5daf0296834><ec4dde54d00305ebbec62f3f6bbca974>]/Root 5 0 R/Size 7/Info 6 0 R>>
%iText-5.4.3
startxref
595
%%EOF
```

In this snippet `startxref` marks the byte offset of `xref` which is where the cross-reference table starts. This table contains the byte-offsets of all the objects in the PDF.

When you look at the PDF you refer to, you see that it ends like this:

```
64 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 5/Predictor 12>>/Encrypt 972 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<85C47EA3EFE49E4CB0F087350055FDDC><C3F1748360D0464FBA02D711DE864630>]/Info 970 0 R/Length 283/Root 973 0 R/Size 971/Type/XRef/W[1 3 1]>>stream
hÞìÒ±JQÐ™·»7J¢©ÕØ(Xþ„ù »h%¤É¤¶”€mZ+;ÁN,,ÁÆ6 XÁ&‚("î½YŒI‘Bî‡áÎ¼]ö1Áð÷³cfþ‹ûÐÚLî`zÂ„Ýôœùw÷N×X?Ã™kNv`hÁÒj¦G[œiÀå»›œ?b½Än…ÉëàÍþ gY—i7WW‡òj®îÍ°u¸Ò‡Ñ:óÆÛ™ñÎë&'×Ýˆ§ü†ù!ÿñ€ù%,\ácçÙ9˜ì±Þ€S¼Ãd—‰Áy~×.ø¶Åìþßn_˜$9Ôüw£X9#åxzçgRüüóÙwÝ¡œÄNJ©½’Ú+©½’R{%µWR{%ÿ·á”;`_ z6Ø
endstream
endobj
startxref
116
%%EOF
```

In this case, `startxref` still refers to where the first cross-reference table starts (it's a linearized PDF), but the cross reference table is stored inside an object, and that object is compressed (see the gibberish between the `stream` and `endstream` keywords).

Compressed cross-reference tables and compressed objects were introduced in PDF 1.5 (2003), but they aren't supported by PdfTk. You'll have to find a tool that can deal with such streams (e.g. a recent version of iText, which is the real stuff when compared to PdfTk), or you have to save your PDF as a PDF 1.4 before you treat it with PdfTk (but you'll lose the XFA, because XFA was also introduced in PDF 1.5).

**Update:**

Since you are asking about form fields, I'm adding the following attachment:

[image]

This screenshot was taken using [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups) (which proves that iText can open the document). To the right, you see that the same form is defined twice:

[image]

If you would walk down the tree under `Fields`, you'd find all the fields that are stored in the PDF using AcroForm technology. To the left, you can see the description of such a field:

[image]

If you look under XFA, you notice that the same form is also defined using the XML Forms Architecture. If you click on `datasets`, you see the XML description of the dataset in the lower panel:

[image]

All of this information can be accessed programmatically using iText (Java) or iTextSharp (C#). PdfTk is merely a tool based on a very old version of this technology.

Comment: can you please refer a library for that

Comment: I mentioned [iText](http://itextpdf.com) which is available in Java and C#. As I explained: you are already using an obsolete version of iText when you are using PdfTk. Recent versions of iText support files with compressed cross-reference tables. I'll add an [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups) screen shot to my answer.

Comment: can i use itext with php??